# Parent div overflow -x is not working

Tags: html, css, frontend

Inside parent div there are many child divs, I'm trying to apply `overflow-x` prop, but it isn't working, I have attached my code, please give some solutions

```css
<style>
.parent{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background:#ccc;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.child{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: what exactly is not working? overflow-x: hidden? what are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: here  everything is well!

Comment: Do you want to scroll child divs only with overflow-x scrollbar?

Comment: Your child elements never overflow. They are with a fixed width and the parent is always bigger. Isn't that the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found what you needed. you need one more extra div to have all your child divs in one row, otherwise they will break in more lines.
try this please:

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="inner">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div>
    <div class="child">
    </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

and for css :

```
.inner{
  width:2000px;
  height:300px;
}
.parent{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background:#ccc;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: none;
}
.child{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float:left;
display:block;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: still its not working                                                                             <style>
.parent{
width: 100%;
height: 300px;
background:#ccc;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
.child{
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="parent">
 <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div>
    <div class="child"> </div> 
</div>
</body>